# Sorting icons needs to right align in DataGrid

Tags: gwt

I use sorting in [Datagrid](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDataGrid). The sorting icons display on left align default. I needs to show it on right. How can I set it on right align? see below image for "No" column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show sorting icons left align, applied below style.  It works.

```
.cellTableStyle th > div:first-child {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.cellTableStyle th div div:first-child {
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: 100%;
}
```